# Android post request to django server using HttpUrlConnection gives 403

Tags: android, python, django, cookies

I am learning networking in android using a django server. I am able to make GET requests and get the json response as well as I am able to get the csrf cookie, but when I use the cookie and make a post request , django gives 403 that says csrf verification failed.

I am setting the required header 'X-CSRFToken' with csrf token and also passing the cookies (cookieString) but no success till now.

Here are my classes in android. I am able to make post requests using python-requests library so there is no problem in django server, there is some issue in this android code. Please suggest any way to solve this problem.

```
private void signupUser() {
    validateData();
    new PostData().execute();
}

private void validateData() {
    try {
        urlParameters= URLEncoder.encode("code","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("100","utf-8");
        urlParameters+= "&"+URLEncoder.encode("username","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"utf-8");
        urlParameters+= "&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"utf-8");
        urlParameters+= "&"+URLEncoder.encode("firstName","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(firstName,"utf-8");
        urlParameters+= "&"+URLEncoder.encode("lastName","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(lastName,"utf-8");
        urlParameters+= "&"+URLEncoder.encode("email","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class PostData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String response="";

        try {

            // Manage Cookies
            String cookieString="";
            String csrftoken="";


            cookieManager=io.getCookiesFromURLConnection(urlConnection);
            List<HttpCookie> cookies=cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            Iterator<HttpCookie> cookieIterator=cookies.iterator();
            while(cookieIterator.hasNext()){
                HttpCookie cookie=cookieIterator.next();
                cookieString+=cookie.getName()+"="+cookie.getValue()+";";

                if(cookie.getName().equals("csrftoken")){
                    csrftoken=cookie.getValue();
                }
            }


            url= new URL(Utils.USER_SIGNUP_URL);
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", Utils.USER_AGENT);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", Utils.KEEP_ALIVE);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookies", cookieString);

            OutputStreamWriter streamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            streamWriter.write(urlParameters);
            streamWriter.flush();
            streamWriter.close();
            int responseCode=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            response=io.readStream(urlConnection);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            try {
                response=io.readErrorStream(urlConnection);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(checkConnection()){
            try {
                return fetchData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Please connect to internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(s==null){
            return ;
        }
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

}

private boolean checkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    String result = "";
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public  String fetchData() throws IOException {

    String result="";

    try {
        url= new URL(Utils.USER_SIGNUP_URL);
        urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        result=io.readStream(urlConnection);
        cookieManager=io.getCookiesFromURLConnection(urlConnection);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}

}
```

Here is the io class:
    public class io {

```
public static CookieManager getCookiesFromURLConnection(HttpURLConnection urlConnection){
    Map<String,List<String >> headers= urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
    CookieManager cookieManager=new CookieManager();
    List<String> cookiesHeader=headers.get("Set-Cookie");

    if(cookiesHeader!=null){
        for(String cookie: cookiesHeader){
            cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
        }
    }

    return cookieManager;
}

}
```

Android Logcat:

```
09-19 20:55:37.479  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://<website-ip-address>/api/user-login/
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at kam.app.learnnetworking.networking.io.readStream(io.java:28)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at kam.app.learnnetworking.activities.SignUpActivity$PostData.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:172)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at kam.app.learnnetworking.activities.SignUpActivity$PostData.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:123)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-19 20:55:37.484  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Is there any way I can get the sent request and print in android logs? I am new to android networking so don't have much idea.

Comment: Please trim your question to contain only the relevant code instead of just dumping the entire project, far more likely to have people read it that way!

Comment: I have edited the question, but there was no need of a downvote for that.

Comment: very first error line in logcat:09-19 20:55:37.479  17085-17734/kam.app.learnnetworking W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://<website-ip-address>/api/user-login/

Comment: ie check value of HttpUrlconnection var

Comment: @Fred thanks but it is giving filenotfound for the response 403. When I use readErrorStream it gives me the html for the csrf failed response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. It was very silly mistake.

Instead of :

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookies", cookieString);
```

it should have been:

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the android project and django project might be on seperate servers. So, the request fails due to CORS. For example, if you're using tastypie for django apis, then you've to set the CORS like this:

```
class CORSResource(object):
"""
Adds CORS headers to resources that subclass this.
"""
def create_response(self, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(CORSResource, self).create_response(*args, **kwargs)
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
    return response

def method_check(self, request, allowed=None):
    if allowed is None:
        allowed = []

    request_method = request.method.lower()
    allows = ','.join(map(str.upper, allowed))

    if request_method == 'options':
        response = HttpResponse(allows)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
        response['Allow'] = allows
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=response)

    if not request_method in allowed:
        response = http.HttpMethodNotAllowed(allows)
        response['Allow'] = allows
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=response)
```

You've to add CORS headers as such to any thing that's cross domain. You can customize this depending on the framework and the methods you want to allow.

Comment: Hi Vatsal. I am not using any third-party app for apis. I am simply sending JsonResponse. Can you please tell how to enable CORS with that?

Comment: Thanks. But which url to put in  " CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST" because I am using android app.I don't want to compromise with the security by allowing all.

Comment: @KamalSingh in your case. You'll have to use this CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True. And leave the others as default

Comment: Thanks Vatsal, I will try that and see if it works. But won't it be a security issue?

Comment: Yes it does increase the risk. One of the reasons why it isn't allowed by default. However, the risk can be mitigated by using authentication like API key, oauth, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help.